# Why do soft cheeses made by gentiles, like cottage cheese, have a hechsher, while others like mozzarella not have a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, dairy

I noticed [Rav Abadi says](http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=52113&highlight=Soft%20cheese) all soft cheeses made by gentiles are kosher.

Do other poskim also hold like him? 
If yes please post who.

Both cottage cheese and mozzarella require rennet, so I'm not sure why companies like OU make a difference. Why do soft cheeses made by gentiles, like cottage cheese, have a hechsher, while others like mozzarella not have a hechsher?

Comment: i believe you are mistaken, cottage cheese and mozzarella don't require rennet: http://vegetarian.lovetoknow.com/Are_There_Any_Cheeses_that_Do_Not_Contain_Rennet

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. R Abadi in general relies on the ingredient list (and some manufacturing knowledge) to determine if something is Kosher. What is unique about cheese in the question? VTC as Unclear.

Comment: Note by the way that the OU probably would require a hechsher on soft cheeses, but not because of Gevinat Akum issues.

Comment: @Double AA
Cheese is a seperate issue as there is a special takanah. Rav Abadi does not matir any wine based off of ingredients, as there is a special takanah. Please note I wrote about soft cheeses. Rav Abadi does not matir hard cheeses

Comment: @Aaron that list just shows cheeses that use vegetarian rennet.

Comment: @yis I know that. What are you asking for? A list of what cheeses have the gezera? Mozzarella has a Hekhsher all the time.

Comment: @Yishaq "The term “vegetable rennet” means it is derived from a vegetable source. Soft cheeses such as cream cheese and cottage cheese are manufactured without rennet. Some cottage cheeses, however, may contain gelatin which is derived from animal sources. All labels should be read carefully." http://cheese.joyousliving.com/

Comment: As far as i know, the OU relies on the same logic as Rabbi Abadi, and so even though they put a hecsher on soft cheeses, they do so without doing any kind of supervision as the process itself is automatically kosher. Which means that the difference between the unhechshered mozzarella and the hecshered mozzarella is one company decided to buy the right to use the hecsher, and one didn't

Comment: @Aaron can you please provide a source? I am pretty sure they require a new to pour in the rennet, as the Bach requires.